# How to get rid of the warning: Use '$' instead of '.' for inner classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-manifest

I am new to Android development. After I updated my eclipse and Android SDK to the newest version, I got an warning:

```
Use '$' instead of '.' for inner classes (or use only lowercase letters in package names)   AndroidManifest.xml
```

I Found some information on this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/7ce6049cd1d368d7cd08ac5e22f855f23b2110a7%5E1..7ce6049cd1d368d7cd08ac5e22f855f23b2110a7/).

```
"When you reference an inner class in a manifest file, you must use '$' instead of '.' " +
    "as the separator character, e.g. Outer$Inner instead of Outer.Inner.\n" +
    "\n" +
    "(If you get this warning for a class which is not actually an inner class, it's " +
    "because you are using uppercase characters in your package name, which is not " +
    "conventional.)"
```

I believe that I used uppercase characters in sub package name like `com.abc.app.Promotion`.

The question is: What is the best way to get rid of this warning in the manifest.xml? It still can build and run but I find it so annoying.

I tried using refactor to rename the package and modified the manifest.xml `android:name="com.abc.app.promotion.Promotion"` but got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.app/com.abc.app.TabView}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.abc.app/com.abc.app.promotion.Promotion}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Thanks for helping!

EDIT:
original manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".Promotion.Promotion" ></activity>
```

updated manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="promotion.Promotion" ></activity>
```

Comment: use lowercase characters only for package names.

Comment: yes, I understand. I made that mistake in previous version of the SDK without warning and wish to change it back now. Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you get this warning for a class which is not actually an inner class, it's because you are using **uppercase characters in your package name**, which is not conventional.

I tried also to change only the first letter of the package name to be lower case, the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

You must use **lower case** in your package name

or add this atrr in application tag

```
tools:ignore="InnerclassSeparator"
```

To **Ignore** this Waring