# Why use '$' instead of '.'?

Tags: android, manifest

In my AndroidManifest.xml i have a warning in the line code below.

```
<service android:name=".Helper.LocationService"/>
```

The warning is:

> Inner classes should use $ rather than .  When you reference an inner
>   class in a manifest file, you must use '$' instead of '.' as the
>   separator character, i.e. Outer$Inner instead of Outer.Inner.

So, Why use '$' instead of '.', if when I use '.' still works?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32985736/3364266 check this

Comment: Also $ is the conventional inner class resolver for Java loaders. But its looks like here it's optional

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java compiled classes contain dollar signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388840/java-compiled-classes-contain-dollar-signs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is suggested to use `$` in order not to confuse the outer class name with the package name. So `$` when you want to refer to an `InnerClass` and `.` when referring to the package.

For example if `Helper` is a package name then (lowercase is suggested for package names):

```
<service android:name=".helper.LocationService"/>
```

where if `Helper` is a class and `LocationService` is an inner class defined inside `Helper`

```
<service android:name=".Helper$LocationService"/>
```

Comment: I get it! `Helper` was a package, so I refactored it and the warning disappeared. THANKS!